# interpolation not working as expected in numpy

Tags: python, matlab, numpy, interpolation

I have this line in Matlab for interpolation

```
result = interp1(1:size(STD_TOT,2),STD_TOT,0.1:0.1:size(STD_TOT,2));
```

STD_TOT is 1x1929 matrix.

```
STD_TOT = np.array([0.022329,0.038252,0.026183,0.039864,0.071397,0.0093877,0.035645,0.038868,0.03461,0.034803,0.025023,0.019119,0.017909,0.027522,0.015599,0.030965,0.026065,0.019646,0.010998,0.036017,0.022335,0.012585,0.012451,0.024021,0.043432,0.024585,0.014803,0.034245,0.019898,0.013361,0.034312,0.015459,0.022039,0.018407,0.014185,0.048709,0.020163,0.02464,0.022362,0.033791,0.02098,0.034847,0.036605,0.056101,0.031263,0.030014,0.021896,0.015648,0.024781,0.028309,0.016281,0.0431,0.020367,0.026632,0.031055,0.020638,0.014622,0.020314,0.021677,0.030235,0.010894,0.053212,0.030193,0.040845,0.018514,0.01545,0.01966,0.019973,0.021554,0.025247,0.016069,0.020857,0.051112,0.019685,0.029247,0.032883,0.024137,0.016086,0.019584,0.020601,0.038225,0.032787,0.038193,0.038704,0.040892,0.019453,0.014094,0.031956,0.031874,0.022639,0.009977,0.014328,0.021327,0.013044,0.037236,0.035503,0.013499,0.026244,0.042117,0.029735,0.028568,0.022035,0.0194,0.031031,0.027281,0.044277,0.049653,0.020843,0.032636,0.050632,0.017949,0.026104,0.030283,0.025735,0.02773,0.03135,0.024075,0.021725,0.044103,0.028657,0.036161,0.037019,0.014675,0.024615,0.035998,0.024762,0.042733,0.035526,0.02677,0.041185,0.02745,0.021578,0.021833,0.046297,0.016011,0.028951,0.028348,0.02166,0.046997,0.042914,0.040323,0.042291,0.019256,0.054203,0.032817,0.033148,0.016921,0.030333,0.012058,0.039489,0.042225,0.020339,0.025997,0.027625,0.022611,0.033546,0.012554,0.017962,0.031922,0.023653,0.036005,0.023482,0.028295,0.02642,0.050785,0.039021,0.042122,0.014519,0.02544,0.056455,0.018666,0.034605,0.010628,0.026576,0.019497,0.020497,0.03705,0.029816,0.014576,0.03366,0.039112,0.017656,0.036429,0.034597,0.031483,0.014713,0.03646,0.015075,0.044297,0.031185,0.011556,0.015206,0.050224,0.02956,0.029094,0.027794,0.014398,0.027187,0.030275,0.020356,0.019366,0.026373,0.02762,0.019375,0.031252,0.02682,0.033598,0.026522,0.027045,0.036862,0.033649,0.034089,0.039592,0.035529,0.023636,0.016788,0.03317,0.026586,0.032033,0.034494,0.028918,0.023945,0.020192,0.025029,0.031529,0.03667,0.023747,0.018255,0.016018,0.022538,0.042874,0.030096,0.020491,0.050092,0.060774,0.026128,0.040431,0.014238,0.035462,0.021367,0.0583,0.03295,0.029522,0.031833,0.033358,0.012864,0.035956,0.018936,0.029752,0.039676,0.042408,0.044228,0.043047,0.028416,0.013676,0.026593,0.020451,0.050606,0.017889,0.038882,0.023015,0.015717,0.032897,0.035794,0.028359,0.038919,0.029727,0.024311,0.022122,0.028691,0.043846,0.018395,0.02904,0.039923,0.025166,0.012168,0.028931,0.045164,0.029121,0.014628,0.027836,0.018975,0.044044,0.028019,0.018852,0.021688,0.021433,0.022567,0.061596,0.028267,0.026423,0.036605,0.034917,0.036271,0.051461,0.021171,0.042466,0.032582,0.025327,0.04121,0.027905,0.019709,0.033487,0.019911,0.03359,0.021397,0.016932,0.024646,0.029238,0.055602,0.048563,0.024637,0.02818,0.038765,0.041247,0.026434,0.037542,0.013241,0.040208,0.021881,0.029172,0.032603,0.014366,0.027467,0.036551,0.018443,0.018644,0.020188,0.025156,0.027236,0.0099204,0.016394,0.048622,0.034403,0.018264,0.024056,0.042391,0.034741,0.03781,0.040637,0.038293,0.047626,0.03222,0.052035,0.059862,0.021805,0.047009,0.028036,0.024544,0.046868,0.016165,0.042088,0.042227,0.026629,0.021114,0.02646,0.01066,0.01689,0.032055,0.022861,0.020576,0.05078,0.029618,0.035833,0.025752,0.027176,0.024259,0.056875,0.010132,0.040195,0.010666,0.020579,0.037731,0.043279,0.024892,0.025875,0.037102,0.04086,0.018498,0.020935,0.015409,0.034974,0.029078,0.030111,0.026621,0.032958,0.014195,0.018914,0.032704,0.051672,0.026541,0.022714,0.018241,0.033349,0.029834,0.023155,0.034582,0.01063,0.021019,0.02166,0.039109,0.032219,0.039032,0.020621,0.026198,0.023946,0.020816,0.019785,0.032674,0.036057,0.04159,0.039924,0.021563,0.046594,0.032643,0.022293,0.022028,0.036636,0.042724,0.047944,0.032415,0.013212,0.017096,0.052169,0.055225,0.056717,0.040754,0.023486,0.06286,0.019585,0.018377,0.024246,0.035979,0.046791,0.058404,0.029826,0.018263,0.020493,0.030886,0.02261,0.019849,0.037998,0.014191,0.042558,0.018117,0.017677,0.011638,0.019193,0.0080181,0.033134,0.014569,0.01548,0.030649,0.022548,0.035944,0.034413,0.025217,0.041429,0.045781,0.041091,0.043901,0.020679,0.022749,0.025157,0.026714,0.038419,0.008342,0.037259,0.038031,0.043106,0.036875,0.020294,0.031025,0.030877,0.018485,0.013781,0.024489,0.015032,0.026092,0.022424,0.039617,0.024482,0.022345,0.034068,0.049616,0.033735,0.017974,0.023128,0.02093,0.024287,0.033454,0.022382,0.026246,0.016094,0.016744,0.013366,0.022421,0.031676,0.025721,0.025856,0.032816,0.027062,0.014572,0.029425,0.022217,0.031412,0.018368,0.027687,0.034196,0.075521,0.045964,0.036377,0.052,0.0088308,0.018229,0.016379,0.025125,0.010334,0.020826,0.025311,0.013864,0.041529,0.049741,0.016391,0.009475,0.048084,0.027836,0.01493,0.038363,0.030732,0.026124,0.045666,0.032532,0.030533,0.031222,0.028714,0.039509,0.029956,0.0099307,0.037462,0.022162,0.063131,0.025582,0.04004,0.037868,0.023492,0.042405,0.042756,0.029407,0.026981,0.017501,0.017497,0.047283,0.029374,0.027398,0.028248,0.011992,0.012935,0.017833,0.023347,0.026074,0.027691,0.045202,0.030252,0.05262,0.017721,0.016419,0.036869,0.023086,0.031797,0.033521,0.024104,0.04369,0.016933,0.035246,0.046722,0.022615,0.027258,0.014288,0.021893,0.011484,0.046691,0.028395,0.055658,0.021721,0.068836,0.040583,0.036728,0.039323,0.016909,0.03205,0.013964,0.02491,0.016633,0.022312,0.0394,0.030203,0.022514,0.034493,0.024953,0.02953,0.02831,0.020379,0.010435,0.030164,0.034972,0.025184,0.024949,0.027266,0.041577,0.056684,0.033046,0.046038,0.033414,0.029407,0.011009,0.029176,0.029561,0.015599,0.018245,0.051056,0.031739,0.023964,0.024095,0.033294,0.030928,0.022744,0.035246,0.03564,0.025558,0.026809,0.014535,0.050954,0.033901,0.033042,0.012584,0.032985,0.048019,0.035184,0.031923,0.028895,0.021082,0.023182,0.030009,0.012081,0.039088,0.026131,0.015373,0.021606,0.033198,0.02069,0.025535,0.03069,0.026994,0.053746,0.021215,0.033571,0.035177,0.027385,0.022777,0.012796,0.027303,0.018554,0.040214,0.02889,0.022185,0.013968,0.038076,0.035668,0.029272,0.0083521,0.018435,0.011951,0.034352,0.020537,0.023351,0.020918,0.01006,0.025168,0.032371,0.022621,0.028398,0.01708,0.03873,0.039124,0.034004,0.025345,0.035443,0.036163,0.031728,0.043544,0.017324,0.029019,0.028999,0.03802,0.025405,0.033584,0.040586,0.023033,0.011556,0.028756,0.045474,0.028059,0.02693,0.011902,0.020323,0.032023,0.034325,0.020424,0.030907,0.05922,0.048044,0.020282,0.037873,0.0082711,0.027276,0.038818,0.026947,0.041542,0.052817,0.048156,0.019459,0.026333,0.018723,0.043548,0.022401,0.020937,0.02289,0.040309,0.028198,0.022128,0.016166,0.031992,0.039932,0.02779,0.014154,0.015705,0.030072,0.03481,0.025477,0.018468,0.029963,0.040526,0.03147,0.041181,0.036134,0.026751,0.042177,0.054422,0.042116,0.042707,0.038512,0.02534,0.035392,0.040469,0.019909,0.039934,0.046701,0.024582,0.030004,0.026266,0.036466,0.031101,0.019599,0.027902,0.030615,0.024645,0.023222,0.035693,0.011624,0.044158,0.036115,0.047834,0.025748,0.018017,0.027874,0.043113,0.039237,0.026508,0.024568,0.024052,0.042086,0.030164,0.024587,0.053807,0.033232,0.055637,0.026632,0.026042,0.02267,0.032493,0.02795,0.028049,0.029657,0.030322,0.036592,0.020004,0.026078,0.031954,0.04015,0.024004,0.035671,0.026479,0.010133,0.046674,0.030052,0.032568,0.024356,0.022712,0.026289,0.047771,0.050184,0.024432,0.027841,0.021617,0.018491,0.052939,0.0259,0.023734,0.020327,0.02597,0.035415,0.032313,0.037956,0.030631,0.034719,0.0085772,0.025296,0.020427,0.045284,0.020721,0.027152,0.017166,0.016513,0.025675,0.028046,0.028014,0.047725,0.042106,0.018162,0.027686,0.057042,0.024114,0.036193,0.021122,0.028452,0.027551,0.021247,0.05004,0.032899,0.016082,0.023866,0.021562,0.020674,0.028623,0.024403,0.053553,0.026819,0.042618,0.022124,0.041702,0.042851,0.036108,0.033308,0.025049,0.04601,0.018663,0.030405,0.017866,0.034941,0.023067,0.024566,0.0095008,0.020531,0.014453,0.03058,0.030466,0.033726,0.035664,0.028702,0.03203,0.019231,0.04927,0.035915,0.033286,0.033455,0.02432,0.034378,0.046743,0.013677,0.025769,0.022085,0.020373,0.018305,0.031075,0.026403,0.043138,0.021282,0.053073,0.041486,0.059257,0.033518,0.045486,0.02119,0.031219,0.031101,0.018581,0.044978,0.042809,0.017587,0.028983,0.04473,0.020322,0.065585,0.01469,0.020686,0.03024,0.019655,0.039822,0.060428,0.01672,0.018946,0.019767,0.0274,0.027793,0.021639,0.031522,0.029096,0.042156,0.039012,0.02813,0.028055,0.026935,0.045269,0.031982,0.032835,0.036206,0.050057,0.035707,0.078836,0.021072,0.017691,0.041988,0.037314,0.020804,0.018739,0.050888,0.047921,0.039605,0.023658,0.047814,0.039523,0.092816,0.041182,0.034051,0.017692,0.029037,0.039792,0.068948,0.031522,0.017792,0.023905,0.029116,0.026693,0.01917,0.0072123,0.040452,0.053766,0.032927,0.027257,0.025645,0.039503,0.046112,0.049505,0.026343,0.024483,0.035541,0.023825,0.028016,0.024578,0.027766,0.021406,0.020138,0.019434,0.050795,0.018637,0.018521,0.057854,0.051053,0.040931,0.023092,0.029148,0.018579,0.01553,0.028171,0.052252,0.025448,0.024231,0.038284,0.032646,0.026903,0.026741,0.033477,0.017554,0.03396,0.041628,0.013684,0.029484,0.027351,0.016248,0.02465,0.038729,0.014943,0.023378,0.064801,0.032061,0.05296,0.015815,0.040153,0.032866,0.024873,0.044957,0.027527,0.031038,0.033607,0.026635,0.037675,0.022087,0.017297,0.045167,0.039847,0.053586,0.026484,0.025011,0.036486,0.03164,0.028543,0.028704,0.029583,0.030018,0.026214,0.018509,0.033342,0.033039,0.031533,0.040105,0.028327,0.024234,0.04663,0.044949,0.025245,0.019148,0.027216,0.030848,0.056266,0.022105,0.040988,0.032845,0.020474,0.043795,0.039649,0.058171,0.054875,0.046187,0.055535,0.065442,0.018564,0.045367,0.027039,0.020264,0.037778,0.05879,0.026449,0.036412,0.046594,0.028539,0.03723,0.033415,0.033785,0.051218,0.031482,0.048633,0.055543,0.033911,0.02959,0.040484,0.056189,0.068937,0.025864,0.023404,0.052159,0.030868,0.019665,0.034358,0.039885,0.024897,0.041261,0.025959,0.035039,0.040594,0.039662,0.047237,0.057464,0.030734,0.048807,0.02391,0.029108,0.061478,0.028634,0.024943,0.036522,0.041691,0.06256,0.025549,0.040788,0.02548,0.053724,0.027477,0.029337,0.035578,0.024926,0.037397,0.029968,0.037229,0.049301,0.026322,0.055619,0.052853,0.033469,0.042197,0.034536,0.037851,0.026851,0.037635,0.039721,0.016364,0.037911,0.035201,0.028521,0.03435,0.015901,0.03171,0.018389,0.022068,0.031644,0.03489,0.027287,0.055739,0.035075,0.026661,0.016963,0.022528,0.031414,0.048256,0.033816,0.041254,0.01993,0.035191,0.04404,0.038827,0.030298,0.02551,0.026456,0.03765,0.029708,0.026444,0.027081,0.032207,0.036741,0.040606,0.037882,0.040422,0.064415,0.037922,0.018835,0.028095,0.035046,0.06864,0.021208,0.020899,0.032012,0.041264,0.027568,0.021001,0.025015,0.040758,0.04408,0.033928,0.034658,0.055439,0.021127,0.046304,0.042591,0.068578,0.048074,0.044822,0.045545,0.064277,0.03382,0.021841,0.039165,0.03186,0.046677,0.025795,0.062887,0.049566,0.045905,0.038352,0.03577,0.059277,0.047006,0.026764,0.022885,0.055025,0.054044,0.037502,0.039364,0.023891,0.05645,0.036933,0.038076,0.015446,0.033398,0.01255,0.052303,0.038554,0.024542,0.025485,0.067901,0.02107,0.052371,0.014771,0.04972,0.020514,0.045068,0.039001,0.020706,0.028487,0.050018,0.045312,0.057855,0.019473,0.025423,0.030273,0.021741,0.027731,0.026181,0.026256,0.03752,0.033919,0.036526,0.019823,0.035227,0.03128,0.061728,0.026137,0.022327,0.036531,0.044059,0.019296,0.063932,0.043101,0.022319,0.048824,0.044803,0.027017,0.043061,0.046871,0.04923,0.035523,0.038898,0.034789,0.015619,0.059337,0.029834,0.022216,0.040871,0.046292,0.046846,0.028197,0.013579,0.026942,0.056113,0.045024,0.04704,0.018772,0.034849,0.055848,0.038775,0.052496,0.02694,0.018795,0.039311,0.041433,0.067658,0.017813,0.035696,0.047525,0.041886,0.031605,0.041554,0.069013,0.046658,0.059725,0.022272,0.046527,0.032625,0.036472,0.026408,0.035244,0.027797,0.021314,0.033122,0.035446,0.061782,0.044833,0.045089,0.036683,0.051836,0.033406,0.019746,0.031404,0.019582,0.055357,0.05218,0.040144,0.023201,0.034386,0.042104,0.033136,0.048065,0.044285,0.047815,0.029137,0.029262,0.03646,0.03697,0.048973,0.034631,0.060904,0.040718,0.021191,0.037079,0.039662,0.029304,0.028917,0.06233,0.077933,0.031883,0.030603,0.023746,0.030293,0.04703,0.044857,0.051221,0.036498,0.047829,0.045227,0.027666,0.059143,0.035813,0.065883,0.032474,0.038207,0.04386,0.047207,0.03528,0.054688,0.037548,0.044005,0.047996,0.026909,0.0084502,0.046723,0.059546,0.044528,0.028388,0.032335,0.065694,0.044778,0.035267,0.028994,0.02827,0.026294,0.029045,0.078864,0.064347,0.048763,0.053859,0.039902,0.031368,0.056329,0.072665,0.046209,0.023212,0.071945,0.056526,0.026561,0.032042,0.060904,0.075322,0.011773,0.038112,0.021674,0.034664,0.049693,0.034299,0.027133,0.10195,0.071211,0.042567,0.03455,0.050446,0.048874,0.034895,0.024369,0.026936,0.032121,0.047222,0.056907,0.081895,0.077119,0.045017,0.040331,0.035668,0.027682,0.043664,0.030195,0.020562,0.046164,0.040572,0.068749,0.031872,0.066324,0.059153,0.066077,0.025598,0.028489,0.045578,0.022503,0.026981,0.043312,0.050483,0.046576,0.03097,0.037022,0.053494,0.02356,0.048457,0.047625,0.065204,0.041298,0.043525,0.068468,0.066846,0.027086,0.031603,0.029001,0.043829,0.04572,0.036381,0.046655,0.056732,0.054175,0.034463,0.033894,0.032508,0.07218,0.042355,0.04348,0.050892,0.01843,0.036366,0.042044,0.025184,0.070842,0.038672,0.047461,0.059507,0.076366,0.056331,0.048265,0.017781,0.039299,0.025069,0.034901,0.06488,0.049733,0.027146,0.04767,0.056147,0.04675,0.054932,0.048338,0.033334,0.034283,0.017888,0.052388,0.048355,0.054179,0.048017,0.044535,0.047616,0.034098,0.040134,0.03856,0.043263,0.027567,0.035732,0.06148,0.089302,0.061275,0.045935,0.049981,0.053337,0.043506,0.079107,0.033,0.054749,0.050067,0.063257,0.04321,0.064843,0.054773,0.066091,0.024045,0.060302,0.051472,0.040709,0.038643,0.044466,0.059754,0.054022,0.056972,0.070806,0.075095,0.047195,0.032632,0.043714,0.034575,0.026714,0.06628,0.071003,0.026288,0.048715,0.025186,0.039578,0.080529,0.058661,0.090702,0.051839,0.045786,0.056796,0.059301,0.053268,0.038283,0.023068,0.065938,0.060807,0.094234,0.041235,0.056804,0.084935,0.04645,0.036275,0.065806,0.070912,0.044204,0.041137,0.044001,0.048239,0.062038,0.064928,0.024888,0.057759,0.068197,0.045903,0.043076,0.041935,0.054019,0.055254,0.033267,0.058443,0.068875,0.061936,0.038009,0.048662,0.084899,0.050233,0.056615,0.048919,0.035078,0.077453,0.029004,0.066579,0.044832,0.055878,0.0991,0.056215,0.066247,0.035161,0.071712,0.07051,0.097213,0.065709,0.046693,0.068532,0.046615,0.054981,0.036351,0.033023,0.057265,0.039962,0.065569,0.081565,0.048965,0.076535,0.044955,0.051052,0.091434,0.067277,0.040913,0.036731,0.074392,0.034297,0.054865,0.046021,0.041123,0.034865,0.036688,0.05203,0.049903,0.05756,0.066083,0.061969,0.057463,0.048313,0.066544,0.071057,0.053889,0.047444,0.04002,0.05012,0.042441,0.05286,0.031326,0.078687,0.071905,0.037067,0.08205,0.06663,0.042562,0.093202,0.066589,0.046799,0.070689,0.031923,0.075445,0.048257,0.071262,0.080071,0.051475,0.043418,0.067148,0.05895,0.029387,0.05639,0.064149,0.084424,0.064724,0.070418,0.061338,0.083366,0.060923,0.024362,0.077858,0.077358,0.032208,0.056292,0.05731,0.045808,0.095459,0.040075,0.060602,0.022919,0.068664,0.027465,0.058077,0.071672,0.052469,0.03158,0.046545,0.043479,0.099945,0.071822,0.025581,0.062155,0.077469,0.053802,0.055059,0.04517,0.05637,0.064898,0.096614,0.062942,0.022506,0.079626,0.030283,0.057247,0.060505,0.062072,0.053903,0.062235,0.054724,0.12549,0.035067,0.080829,0.069411,0.073719,0.073674,0.052633,0.08307,0.057689,0.062157,0.050326,0.061021,0.055608,0.093088,0.091387,0.086965,0.068107,0.10019,0.04142,0.034093,0.051264,0.084868,0.094061,0.068235,0.069166,0.032289,0.090428,0.070202,0.055047,0.071506,0.060191,0.082459,0.1069,0.085751,0.045221,0.073584,0.053703,0.05884,0.08134,0.059214,0.064519,0.044289,0.077376,0.061788,0.066572,0.038216,0.053788,0.082876,0.067532,0.081095,0.03568,0.078921,0.088406,0.049079,0.072008,0.035236,0.058894,0.068371,0.035752,0.057622,0.10127,0.030927,0.069545,0.03278,0.064205,0.054632,0.078552,0.088542,0.068796,0.052508,0.055458,0.048347,0.066663,0.062238,0.050596,0.066373,0.053172,0.051601,0.056556,0.12804,0.043216,0.073941,0.067825,0.052829,0.065981,0.056192,0.1038,0.069696,0.040866,0.065054,0.054401,0.048545,0.029061,0.052503,0.10666,0.046095,0.062982,0.1236,0.076137,0.059244,0.087896,0.079521,0.10331,0.059738,0.066553,0.083443,0.040614,0.053665,0.057264,0.074416,0.07482,0.071717,0.052646,0.072679,0.025502,0.073387,0.030559,0.065377,0.12948,0.069605,0.12078,0.098918,0.058082,0.07118,0.072409,0.081077,0.11927,0.1233,0.056718,0.050254,0.096894,0.12196,0.078496,0.049102,0.072269,0.067632,0.07271,0.0308,0.13332,0.074284,0.064612,0.052841,0.10024,0.053029,0.094159,0.10607,0.11543,0.054529,0.11752,0.12393,0.048672,0.057151,0.06328,0.051109,0.083704,0.034152,0.074567,0.10618,0.061933,0.08989,0.10957,0.072621,0.062222,0.044612,0.084522,0.076588,0.08802,0.085928,0.066853,0.050163,0.052102,0.089316,0.11014,0.06142,0.080851,0.043018,0.13165,0.062093,0.13009,0.1305,0.083476,0.098729,0.072478,0.052251,0.035676,0.092381,0.054997,0.077478,0.11398,0.077775,0.061062,0.08382,0.069045,0.077822,0.049547,0.15232,0.10348,0.04119,0.058516,0.087043,0.12271,0.075315,0.079716,0.077234,0.037982,0.081178,0.10821,0.067529,0.11449,0.095668,0.078472,0.031747,0.073745,0.11623,0.062093])
```

Result is:

```
[NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 0.0223287, 0.023921, 0.0255133, ... , 0.0783331, 0.0729199, 0.0675067, 0.0620934]
```

Please note result is made of 19.290 elements, 9 of which (the first ones) are NA. According to my research they are some kind of missing values or something like that.

I want to achieve the same in Python.

The following is what I already did:

Numpy interp:

```
result = np.interp(np.arange(0.1, STD_TOT.shape[0]+0.1, 0.1), np.arange(1, STD_TOT.size+1, dtype=int), STD_TOT)
```

And the result is

```
[0.022329  0.022329  0.022329  0.022329  0.022329  0.022329  0.022329  0.022329  0.022329 0.022329  0.023921  0.0255136  0.0271059  ... 0.07292 0.06750 0.06209 ]
```

As you can see the result with numpy is EXTREMELY similar to what I have in Matlab but the 9 NA values are replaced by 0.022329 (and I don't want this).

What can I do for having the exact same results? I've been losing my mind on this for a day already, I also tried scipy `interpolate.interp1d` but I couldn't even run it. I am really lost!

Comment: This code is quite a tumble; please [edit] the post to ensure it is clear what is MATLAB code and what is Python, and which things work in either language and which don't. E.g. in your first line of code you say it's MATLAB, but then define a variable using NumPy, which obviously doesn't work in MATLAB. Also please read [mcve] and reduce the code to **minimal**, as opposed to dumping 1929 elements, use e.g. 5 or 6 to get the same problem reproduced.

Comment: hi. It's clear only the first line of code is in Matlab. The STD_TOT array is already Python syntax because I'm making easier for others to reproduce my issue. Can't do with reduced data because of course it would change the result and making the request pointless.

Comment: @claw91 that is not true. You could make an array with 10 values used from your data that reproduces your behaviour (literally just use 10 values of STD_TOT). This is a simple linear interpolation, it can be reduced.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the documentation:

> `numpy.interp(x, xp, fp, left=None, right=None, period=None)`
>
> leftoptional float or complex corresponding to fp Value to return for
>   x < xp[0], default is fp[0].
>
> rightoptional float or complex corresponding to fp Value to return for
>   x > xp[-1], default is fp[-1].

replace `left` and `right` with out of bounds value desired. MATLAB's default is NaN.

Comment: yes, but what if I want to have those NA values in Python? I don't want them to be replaced by other values. This because all mathematical operations after this give me different result than what I expect because there is actual values instead of NA values.

Comment: tried left = np.nan but I don't know if NA equals np.nan to be honest

Comment: @claw91 I its. In fact, AFAIK python does not have NA (definetly numpy does not), its instead NaN. Its essentially the same thing